# Oracle stored procedure works with ADO.NET but with OrmLite throws exception?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a following stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRODUCT_DETAILS(p_code IN VARCHAR2, 
                                            cursorParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN cursorParam FOR
  select str_auth_code, str_name
  from strs
  where str_auth_code = p_code;
END;
```

How can I call it with OrmLite? I've tryied:

```
connection.SqlList<Product>(@"EXEC PRODUCT_DETAILS @p_code", new { p_code = code });
```

but it throws an exception `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

I just tried to do it with plain old ADO.NET and it worked:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "PRODUCT_DETAILS";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_code", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = redemptionCode;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("cursorParam", OracleType.Cursor);
    cmd.Parameters["cursorParam"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"]);

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same task with OrmLite.

Comment: with `@"EXEC PRODUCT_DETAILS (@p_code)"` I get same exception

Comment: when I try it this way it throws `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Comment: I'm trying `EXEC PRODUCT_DETAILS ('ffff-ffff-ffff');`. I also get an error trying to execute it in Oracle Sql Developer: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRODUCT_DETAILS'`. It's because I don't pass `cursorParam`. It would be good if I know what statement is generated by ormlite when I run SqlList with query from my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have looks good. If you were concerned about the verbosity of the code, and were using a number of stored procedures, then you could use this extension method to remove some of the repeated code:

## Extension Method:

```cs
public static class StoredProcExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ExecStoredProcedure<T>(this IDbConnection connection, string procedureName, object parameters = null, string outputCursor = "cursorParam")
    {
        return connection.Exec(c => {
            c.CommandText = procedureName;
            c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Create the parameters from the parameters object
            if(parameters != null)
                foreach(var property in parameters.GetType().GetPublicProperties())
                    c.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(property.Name, property.GetValue(parameters)));

            // Add the output cursor
            if(outputCursor != null)
                c.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(outputCursor, OracleDbType.RefCursor) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

            // Return the result list
            return c.ExecuteReader().ConvertToList<T>();
        });
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
var download = connection.ExecStoredProcedure<ProductDownloads>(
                   "PRODUCT_DETAILS", 
                   new { p_code = redemptionCode }
               );

foreach (var productDownload in download)
{
    Console.WriteLine(productDownload.Name);
}
```

So the arguments are:

1. Stored procedure name *i.e. `PRODUCT_DETAILS`*
2. *Optional* An object of input parameters 
   *i.e `new { p_code = redemptionCode, other = "value" }`*
3. *Optional* The name of the output cursor - defaults to `cursorParam`

*Note: this code is untested, because I don't have Oracle setup, but it does compile, and hopefully goes some way to simplifying your stored procedures.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've known that I could end up with some kind of extention method. But I just wondered if OrmLite supports SP with cursors out of the box. With Dapper it seams more easily to do that...

Comment: @OleksiiAza I am not an expert in the Oracle area, but having [looked at the Oracle provider code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle), [and the SP code here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteSPStatement.cs), I don't see anything to handle the cursored output. I don't think the Oracle dialect provider of OrmLite has received as much development attention to address this issue. It could be something you could feature request for or provide a method in a pull request.

Comment: Yes, I also looked at the source code of `OracleDialectProvider`. Specifically on `.ToExecuteProcedureStatement()`, but it generates code: `begin EXECUTE PROCEDURE PRODUCT_DETAILS (p_code=>:p_code, cursorParam=>:cursorParam) end;` that is not valid in `Oracle SQL Developer`. By the way I'm not an expert in Oracle too, I just started to dig it in the middle of previous week.

Comment: @OleksiiAza I tend to think that the OrmLite dialect provider for Oracle started with the OrmLite Firebird provider, and it's not quite right for Oracle. There are still hints of [Firebird here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle/README.md) and in some of the tests.

Comment: @OleksiiAza I think that the Oracle provider needs some work, it's **not** listed as an [officially supported provider here](http://servicestack.net/download), while other providers are. There is an [open feature request for it's support](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/5439529-support-the-oracle-ormlite-provider).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you for information. But I will wait for more information on the topic, maybe demis himself will answer it or somebody will advice me how to restructure my SP so this doesn't use cursor.

Comment: @OleksiiAza That's cool. I can't see any examples returning rows from an Oracle SP without using a cursor but maybe it's possible.

Comment: @OleksiiAza Hello, I don't think Demis is going to weigh in on this one, as Oracle is not officially supported. Would you be willing now to accept, and this can be changed if the support is ever introduced? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, at least 2.5 month already passed. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So far ended up with following code:

```
using (var connection = factory.Open())
{
    var download = 
         connection.Exec(c =>
          {
               c.CommandText = "PRODUCT_DETAILS";
               c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               c.Parameters.Add(
                  new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("p_code", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.NVarchar2) { Value = redemptionCode });
               c.Parameters.Add(
                   new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("cursorParam", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
                return c.ExecuteReader().ConvertToList<ProductDownloads>();
           });

           foreach (var productDownload in download)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(productDownload.Name);
           }
}
```

But I think there should be a better way for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but this problem can be solved by simply adding `BEGIN` and `END` to the statement... it will work.

In my case, I was trying to refresh a materialized view, only after adding BEGIN and END will it work, otherwise it will throw `OracleException ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement...`

This should work:

```
db.ExecuteSql("BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('" + materializedViewName + "'); END;");
```